# how to insert values to a table with another table data using case statatement

Tags: mysql

[image]
i have a table "test_comparitive_analysis" with  column fields like gender, and value. Another table "cmparitive_analysis_dup" column fields like "boys" and "girls". The problem is that i want to insert all column values of "test_comparitive_analysis" to "cmparitive_analysis_dup". Condition is that if gender is "F" the "value" column data will move to "girls"column anf if it is "M" 
the "value" column data will move to "boys"

how can it possible

[image]

```
  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comparitive_analysis_dup` (
        `cmb_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `class_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
        `division` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
        `boys` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        `girls` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        `subject_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        `exam_name` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
        `term_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`cmb_id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ; "
```

Comment: post your related table structures

Comment: thats my table structure

Comment: I meant to say post your create table code.

Answer (score 0):

Use two case (one for female, one for male)   and a inner join

```
insert into cmparitive_analysis_dup(subject_name, boys, girls)
select a.subject_name,
   sum(case when a.gender = 'F' then a.value else 0 end),
   sum(case when b.gender = 'M' then b.value else 0 end)
from test_comparitive_analysis as a 
inner join test_comparitive_analysis as b on(a.cmb_id = b.cmb_id)
group by a.subject_name
```

Comment: my table rows get replicated according to subject_name

Comment: i want only one row for one single subject .

Comment: sorry.. still it is same

Comment: A last try  .. hope useful